# Unable to update item id with username special characters

Tags: php, sql, paypal

I'm using paypal buttons as payment, the problem is, when the player type the username, and if have special characters the query don't update item quantity, but with normal name it updates.

```
{
  global $first_name, $last_name, $payer_business_name, $custom,$payer_email;
  global $mysql_linklok;
  if (($data == "") || ($data == "NOTREQUIRED") || ($user2==""))
  { 
    $key="Could not update user ".$user2;
    return (string)$key;
  }
  $mysql_linklok=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");    
  if ($mysql_linklok!==false)
  {
    $query="UPDATE users SET points=points + ".$data." WHERE name=".llipn_quote_smart($user2);
    mysqli_query($mysql_linklok,$query);
    mysqli_close($mysql_linklok);
  }
  $key=$data." points added to ".$user2;
  return (string)$key;
```

i've been searching for hours and  tried many options, but not of them works.

can someone help me how to solve it?

Many thanks

Comment: *"and if have special characters the query don't update item quantity"* - What characters are those?

Comment: this can be one example !       ᵛᶤᵖ ๖ۣۜ⛧666⛧' ††

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner what you suggest doesn't help because like i said, if the user have normal characters it updates the point's.

Comment: This username not updated exist?, how is saved?

Comment: name varchar(15) NULL in database they show normal with special characters. but when the user type in php the username the query don't detect special characters

Comment: Consult the duplicates. You need to be quoting string values.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i've done that and still  not working

Comment: Even from paypal email i got this info

Item Number 10p Username: Velamyr III[âˆ†]

which should be this username : Velamyr III[∆]